# What does 'Invalid frame size' mean in Thrift

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Running cassandra 2.1 clusters here where we see few errors like below from time to time:

```
ERROR [Thrift-Selector_15] 2017-07-15 01:08:42,677 Message.java:164 - Invalid frame size got (15826670), maximum expected 15728640
```

Wondering what might be the cause for such and their impact on clusters?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this is telling you that the data size of your upsert is too big.  You have a couple of options here:

1. Modify your application logic to write data in smaller amounts.
2. Increase the `thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb` setting in the cassandra.yaml to something that  better accommodates your write pattern.
3. Change your application to use the native binary protocol, which has a higher default frame size (256MB).

I recommend #3 for the long-term.  For the short term you could experiment with #2.  But Thrift has been deprecated and is disabled by default in the current versions of Cassandra, and will be removed all-together in the near future.